# trying to install opencv from npm on windows

Tags: python, opencv, npm

I am trying to install open-cv for nodeJs on windows 8

I downloaded NodeJs, installed it
Installed python for windows 32 bit [OpenCV 2.3.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/)

```
SET PYTHON=C:\Python33
SET %PATH%;C:\PYTHON33
```

downloaded opencv 3.4.1 from 
then ran
npm install opencv
this is the result:

```
C:\projects>npm install opencv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv
>npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv
>opencv@0.3.1 preinstall C:\copter\node_modules\opencv
node-gyp clean rebuild
C:\projects\node_modules\opencv>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "clean" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\copter\node_modules\opencv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.18
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

update:

Also tried

```
C:\projects\node_modules>npm install opencv-node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv-node
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv-node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv-node/-/opencv-node-0.2.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv-node/-/opencv-node-0.2.6.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress/-/keypress-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.6.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress/-/keypress-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.6.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.5.2.tgz

> opencv-node@0.2.6 install C:\copter\node_modules\opencv-node
> node-gyp configure build


C:\projects\node_modules\opencv-node>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\nod
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.
gyp ERR! cwd C:\copter\node_modules\opencv-node
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.18
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 8 x64 when I tried to install "ldapauth". The error came from node-gyp. Check the Installation notes on https://npmjs.org/package/node-gyp. Also I solved excluding Python from the PATH and setting the variable PYTHON to empty.